# How can we trace expressions / print statements with line numbers in Scala?

Tags: scala, debugging, stack-trace, trace

If you want print statements with line numbers, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

With the [scala-trace-debug](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scala-trace-debug) library, you can type something like this:

```
Debug.trace(1 + 2)
```

And get this:

```
"3" in thread main:
    path.to.file(file.Scala: 22) // click-able stack trace
```

You can customize the number of lines of stack trace, like so:

```
Debug.trace(1 + 2, 3) // 3 lines of stack trace
```

And if you do `info.collaboration_station.debug._`, you can even do this:

```
val three = 3.trace
```

...

```
"3" in thread main:
    path.to.file(file.Scala: 22)
```

Finally, there is support for expressions:

```
Debug.traceExpression{
    val myVal = 4
    1 + 2 + myVal
}
```

...

```
"{
  val myVal = 4;
  (3).+(myVal)
} -> 7" in thread main:
    at main.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
```

Unlike the other library, this is more geared toward debugging. If I wanted to provide a history of what was going on and I did not want the user to see a stack trace, I would not use this tool.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Haoyi Li's [sourcecode](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode) library, I think it gives you what you are looking for.

> sourcecode is a small Scala library for that provides common "source
>   code" context to your program at runtime, similar to Python's
>   __name__, C++'s __LINE__ or Ruby's __FILE__. For example, you can
>   ask for the file-name and line number of the current file, either
>   through the () syntax or via an implicit.

See for example https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode#logging

> You can use sourcecode.File and sourcecode.Line to define log
>   functions that automatically capture their line number and file-name

```
def log(foo: String)(implicit line: sourcecode.Line, file: sourcecode.File) = {
  println(s"${file.value}:${line.value} $foo")
}

log("Foooooo") // sourcecode/shared/src/test/scala/sourcecode/Tests.scala:86 Fooooo
```